# Laravel outer left join

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have the following query for my users table.  I have an additional pivot table for permissions and need to integrate this into my query.

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->join('locations', 'locations.id', '=', 'users.location_id')
            ->where('active', 1)
            ->get(array('users.fullname', 'users.email', 'permissions.granted'))
```

The pivot table consists of

user_persmission (table)

user_id, permission_id

permissions (table)
id
title

Simply, I need my array to have an additional field to indicate if this user has any permission set.  It does not have to show the value, but only set 'granted' to 1 if a row exists.

Note: It is possible for a user to have no permissions as this is not mandatory, and equally they can have more than one permission.

I was thinking of a left outer join but very unsure how to build this into my existing query as it is a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: ->join('locations', 'locations.id', '=', 'users.location_id','LEFT OUTER')

Comment: The locations isn't what I'm having problems with.  It is the permissions table.

Comment: okay looking into issue

Comment: ->join('permissions', 'permissions.user_id', '=', 'users.id','LEFT OUTER') yes left outer join looks perfect option just add this below your join statemenet

Comment: I am getting a 'Column not found' on persmssion.user_id.  There is no user_id in my permissions table

Comment: ->join('user_persmission', 'user_persmission.user_id', '=', 'users.id','LEFT OUTER') and in which table you have "granted" field

Comment: OK that certainly seems to be pointing in the right direction :-)  Do you know how I can get the value in my get array?

Comment: you mean toArray() function.

Comment: It's ok. I added 'user_persmission.permission_id as Permission